# nginx repomd.xml 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, rhel6

I set up the nginx repository as specified at http://wiki.nginx.org/Install

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When I try to install php-fpm, I get the following error

```
http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/6Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: nginx. Please verify its path and try again
```

What is another stable baseurl that I can substitute for this?

Comment: Just report the problem to the repository maintainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the instructions completely:

```
Due to differences between how CentOS, RHEL, and Scientific Linux populate the
$releasever variable, it is necessary to manually replace $releasever with either 
"5" (for 5.x) or "6" (for 6.x), depending upon your OS version.
```

Comment: It looks like the variable is resolving to 6Server as it should.

Comment: nginx.org confirmed that it does need changed to the version number alone.